# h:panelGrid run action after clicking into blank space

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

When I click somewhere inside my panelGrid, it runs action from my commandButton which is inside as well. Whole accordionPanel is inside h:form ..

jsf:

```
    <p:accordionPanel value="#{test.getAllTests()}" var="currentTest" activeIndex="false">   
        <p:tab title="#{currentTest.name}">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/img/testIT/#{currentTest.imageSrc}" width="100" height="100" />
            <p:outputLabel>
                <h2>#{currentTest.name}</h2>
                <p>#{currentTest.description}</p>
                <p:commandButton value="Zvolit test" styleClass="testChoseButton" actionListener="#{test.setSelectedTest(currentTest)}" action="testProgress.xhtml" />
                <p:spacer height="5px" width="20px" style="float: right;" />
                <p:button value="Statistika testu" styleClass="testChoseButton" />
            </p:outputLabel>    
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

test.setSelectedTest(currentTest):

```
    public void setSelectedTest(Test selectedTest) {
    this.selectedTest = selectedTest;
    System.err.println("Selected test: " + selectedTest.getId() + " - " + selectedTest.getName());

}
```

I do not know what more you could need guys. Thnx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing `p:outputLabel`, it generates a HTML `<label>` element which is not what you want. I'd think both these will work:

- `p:outputPanel`
- `h:panelGroup`

They can both produce a HTML `span` or a `div` based on the `layout` attribute.

I'd take `<h:panelGroup>` which is meant for exactly this kind of grouping.

Comment: Awesome! You're right.. I just had to rewrite the same mistake in my <ui:define> ... Thank you for explanation!